# Cannot import form class into view

Tags: django, django-forms

Django newbie here. My view function cannot import the `PostForm class`. All three py files are siblings. The `Post class` from model gets imported successfully though.

Could you please help with this?

**Error Message:**

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/django_projects/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    import blog_app.blog_urls
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/blog_app/blog_urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/blog_app/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import PostForm
ImportError: cannot import name PostForm
```

**views.py:**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm


def post_new(request): 
    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog_app/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text',)
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Did you try ```from app.forms import PostForm```? app being the name of your app.

Comment: in your `views.py`, can you add `from .forms import __file__ as f; print(f) ` to check if it target the right file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I had to make a few modifications to the files structure. Therefore created a `forms` package and added an `__init__.py` module to it. Then renamed the `forms.py` module to `post_forms.py` and moved it into the `forms` package. Now when I import the `PostForm` class like `from blog_app.forms.post_forms import PostForm` it works. Obviously renaming the `forms.py` is not relevant here, but I did so to make the files more organized in case I add forms for other models in the future.

Answer (score 0):

import with app name instead of `.forms`

**views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Post
from <you_app_name>.forms import PostForm


def post_new(request): 
    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog_app/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: do you use pycharm ide ? if use pytharm then first remove import line then click on  form = PostForm() , on the left hand a red signal show and click there and select option import ... let me know